# Changing Drivers on Printer Shares

Tags: drivers, printer

Quick question - I have a printer shared out from a workstation with a handful of users connecting to it via the Share. If I change the driver on the share (for example, from a model specific HP to the HP Universal Driver) - what happens to the users connected to that printer next time they wish to print to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microsoft TechNet's [Update and Manage Printer Drivers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732946.aspx#BKMK_UpdateDrivers):

> To update or change the printer drivers for a printer, use the following procedure. *Client computers automatically download and install the updated printer drivers the next time they attempt to print to the printer*.